# Error when installing MongoDB-related packages - "node-gyp rebuild 2>builderr.log"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node-gyp

I could install these packages in the past, but I must have done something to mess something up. If I try to install anything related to MongoDB, such as:

```
npm install -g mongojs
npm install mongoose
npm install mongoskin
```

This is the error message that shows up:

```
> kerberos@0.0.4 install c:\nodeapps\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos @0.0.4
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.4
mongoose@3.8.21 node_modules\mongoose
--- regexp-clone@0.0.1
--- muri@0.3.1
--- sliced@0.0.5
--- hooks@0.2.1
--- mpath@0.1.1
--- mpromise@0.4.3
--- ms@0.1.0
--- mquery@0.8.0 (debug@0..4)
--- mongodb@1.4.12 (readable-stream@1.0.33)
> bson@0.2.16 install c:\nodeapps\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Can someone tell me how to get the bson to install properly? I don't know why this suddenly stopped working when it worked before. Maybe I deleted something I shouldn't have.

Does this have something to do with C or Python? If so, could someone give me instructions for what to do?

Thanks a lot!!